# RxJava- global error handling in Spring boot

Tags: spring, rx-java2

My service method:

```
public Single<AuthenticationResponse> askForToken(UserRequest user){
    return Maybe.fromCallable(()->
            Unirest.post("https://lawyers-supervisor.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token")
                    .header("content-type", "application/json")
                    .body(String.format("{\"grant_type\": \"password\","+
                                    "\"username\": \"%s\","+
                                    "\"password\": \"%s\","+
                                    "\"audience\": \"%s\","+
                                    "\"scope\": \"offline_access\","+
                                    "\"client_id\":\"%s\","+
                                    "\"client_secret\": \"%s\" }",
                            user.getEmail(),
                            user.getPassword(),
                            audience,
                            clientId,
                            clientSecret))
                    .asJson())
            .flatMapSingle(httpResponse->{
                UserEntity userEntity=userService.getByEmail(user.getEmail()).blockingGet();
                if(Objects.isNull(userEntity))
                    Maybe.error(new UserNotExistsException());
                if(httpResponse.getStatus() != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                    Maybe.error(new AuthenticationException());
                return Mapper.mapHttpResponseToAuthenticationResponse(httpResponse,user.getEmail(),userEntity.getUserId(),userEntity.getRole());
            });
}
```

Global exception handler:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler implements ErrorController {

@ExceptionHandler(UserDuplicateEmailException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleDuplicatedEmailEexception(UserDuplicateEmailException ex, WebRequest request) {
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.CONFLICT;
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, new ErrorTemplate(status, status.value(),
                    "User with email :" + ex.getEmail() + " already exists in database",
                    ex.getMessage(),
                    new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())),
            new HttpHeaders(), status, request);
}

@ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAuthenticationException(AuthenticationException ex, WebRequest request) {
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, new ErrorTemplate(status, status.value(),
                    "Bad password or email",
                    null,
                    new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())),
            new HttpHeaders(), status, request);
}

@ExceptionHandler(UserNotExistsException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> userNotExistsException(AuthenticationException ex, WebRequest request) {
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, new ErrorTemplate(status, status.value(),
                    "User doesn't exists",
                    null,
                    new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())),
            new HttpHeaders(), status, request);
}
@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return "error";
}

@Override
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders
        headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    return null;
}
```

}

The problem is that even the if condition is fullfilled and Maybe.error(...) is hit, the error isn't handled by my global hanlder. I wonder what i missed or why it happen? I don't know if it is caused by handler or by rxJava. Maybe i missed someting important.

Answer (score -1):

`Maybe.error(new AuthenticationException());` - this does nothing but create a new `Maybe` object which is then discarded. You need to return it to have the error propagate.